# Accessing data in VIEW from PRESENTATION layer (MVVM) for datagrid itemsource

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

In my presentation layer (PrintViewModel.cs) I have the following code where I expose my dataset that will be used to populate a datagrid.

```
    public const string ViewFullRecipeGroupingPropertyName = "ViewFullRecipeGrouping";
    public List<ViewFullRecipe> _viewFullRecipeGrouping = new List<ViewFullRecipe>();
    public List<ViewFullRecipe> ViewFullRecipeGrouping
    {
        get { return _viewFullRecipeGrouping; }
        set { Set(ViewFullRecipeGroupingPropertyName, ref _viewFullRecipeGrouping, value, true); }
    }
```

Now in my view layer (PrintPage.xaml.cs) I am creating a datagrid programatically and when done I need to set the itemsource, something like this:

```
    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
    var datagrid = new DataGrid();
    datagrid.ItemsSource = PrintViewModel.ViewFullRecipeGrouping;
    }
```

However this is generating the following error:
    An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Presentation.Print.PrintViewModel.ViewFullRecipeGrouping.get'

I know my dataset is ok because if I set it directly in the XAML it works perfectly fine (for my test datagrid created in the XAML itself).

So, I guess the issue is on HOW I am accessing ViewFullRecipeGrouping from the PRESENTATION layer (in my VIEW layer).

This is how the PrintViewModel is instantiated:

```
public class ViewModelLocator
{
    static ViewModelLocator()
    {
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<PrintViewModel>(true);
    }
    public PrintViewModel Print
    {
        get
        {
            return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<PrintViewModel>();
        }
    }
```

Any ideas or suggestions on either how to get this work or a better way (am I violating MVVM here?)
Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the reason why you are getting this error:

```
An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Presentation.Print.PrintViewModel.ViewFullRecipeGrouping.get'
```

is because you're trying to access the `property` as if it is static. Without knowing too much about your ViewModel class, is the class static itself? If it's not, the way you are trying to access it won't work.. you will need to first instantiate the class, then access the property like so: (you may also need to set the data context)

```
  private PrintViewModel _viewModel = new PrintViewModel();
  private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
    this.DataContext = _viewModel;
    var datagrid = new DataGrid();
    datagrid.ItemsSource = _viewModel.ViewFullRecipeGrouping;
  }
```

I would also like to ask, why are you programmatically creating the DataGrid? Why not define it via XAML and and use DataBinding for the ItemsSource.

Also, I'd like to note that the point of Properties is for encapsulation. You are using a "getter" for a public member variable.. The member variable should actually be private:

```
private List<ViewFullRecipe> _viewFullRecipeGrouping = new List<ViewFullRecipe>();
public List<ViewFullRecipe> ViewFullRecipeGrouping
{
    get { return _viewFullRecipeGrouping; }
    set { Set(ViewFullRecipeGroupingPropertyName, ref _viewFullRecipeGrouping, value, true); }
}
```

**Edit:**
Okay, since you are using a "factory" to get what looks like a singelton instance of the ViewModel, update the code to:

```
  private ViewModelLocator _locator = new ViewModelLocator();
  private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
    var viewModel = _locator.Print; // your ViewModel instance
    var datagrid = new DataGrid();
    datagrid.ItemsSource = viewModel.ViewFullRecipeGrouping;
  }
```

or try setting the DataBinding of the GridView

```
  private ViewModelLocator _locator = new ViewModelLocator();
  private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
    var viewModel = _locator.Print; // your ViewModel instance
    this.DataContext = viewModel;

    var datagrid = new DataGrid();
    var binding = new Binding("ViewFullRecipeGrouping");
    BindingOperations.SetBinding(datagrid, DataGrid.ItemsSource, binding);
  }
```

Comment: From what I can see ViewModel is not static. public class PrintViewModel : ViewModelBase and public abstract class ViewModelBase : ObservableObject, ICleanup. And I need to programmatically create the Datagrids because I have no clue how many I will need (static), this is all determined at run-time depending on the data from the DB

Comment: Why is it my XAML can access ViewFullRecipeGrouping without any issues but my XAML.CS cannot - I find this really odd

Comment: I never actually create an instance of PrintViewModel(), this is part of MVVM framework and it is presentation layer ... and well it just is ... I must exist because the code in it is executed as-is and the XAML can use ViewFullRecipeGrouping as-is in a datagrid binding ... I just can't seem to figure out how to get the XAML.CS to see it ...

Comment: @JSchwartz your ViewModel must be getting instaniated somewhere then. Do you know who's creating it?

Comment: Good call - I just updated the original post with details on this (so found the static) ... but this is all low-level in the MVVM framework (using GalaSoft.MvvmLight;). Why does it work to access in the XAML but not the XAML.CS ....

Comment: @JSchwartz see my Edit. These should work, though, is the DataContext already being set inside the Window's Ctor? If not, you may want to do it there. Let me know and I'll update the code.

Comment: what do you mean by DataContext exactly? The PrintPage : Window Ctor only calls InitializeComponent();

Comment: if it only calls InitializeComponent, you'll have to set the DataContext of the window if you want to do DataBinding. Try the first option I provided to you first (w/out the binding) to see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the rest of your code I can only guess, but it appears that this assignment code is contained in a static method.

```
public static void AssignSource() // I'm guessing at the name here.
{
    var datagrid = new DataGrid();
    //ViewFullRecipeGrouping is not static so will throw the exception.
    datagrid.ItemsSource = PrintViewModel.ViewFullRecipeGrouping;
}
```

If that is the case, you will need to either make the assignment method non-static (most likely easiest fix), put your `ViewFullRecipeGrouping` property in its own static method, or create an instance of the of the property within the context of the assignment code, ie.

```
public static void AssignSource() // I'm guessing at the name here.
{
    PrintViewModel.ViewFullRecipeGrouping = new List<ViewFullRecipe>();
    PrintViewModel.ViewFullRecipeGrouping.Add(new ViewFullRecipe());
    var datagrid = new DataGrid();
    datagrid.ItemsSource = PrintViewModel.ViewFullRecipeGrouping;
}
```

Comment: Actually stored in private void Window_Loaded (I have updated my initial post) ... maybe this isn't the best place to put it? In your suggestion, what would actually call your function AssignSource?

Comment: Also all the code for ViewFullRecipeGrouping is done in the presentation layer, you should not be touching it in the VIEW layer no? I just want to USE the already setup ViewFullRecipeGrouping.

Comment: Where you put it is most likely fine.  We need to find out why you're getting that exception however. Is `PrintViewModel` a static class?

Comment: public class PrintViewModel : ViewModelBase

Comment: public abstract class ViewModelBase : ObservableObject, ICleanup

Comment: See my updated posting showing how we create PrintViewModel (part of the actual MVVM framework using GalaSoft.MvvmLight).